# jQuery: if pass else die

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want method to prevent the code from the resumption of what he is doing if the condition is not true.

This is my code

```
function doSomething{
    if(1==2){
        alert("Can I access to your event?");
    }else{
        //1 not equals 2, so please die
       // I tried die() event; It worked, But i get this error in the console
      //  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'die' of undefined 
    }
}

$(".foo").click(function(){
    doSomething();
    alert("welcome, 1 == 1 is true");
}
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `die()` function by default.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://api.jquery.com/die/)?

Comment: Yes this what i meant

Comment: What do you want to prevent? Only errors "kill" js code, and you don't want an error as you noticed.

Comment: @JimmyTodd how did you call die?

Comment: @JimmyTodd note that `die()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: @zsawyer it was removed entirely 1.9. @JimmyTodd, use `.on()` and `.off()`

Comment: @JimmyTodd: so are you just asking about the usage of the deprecated/obsolete `jQuery.fn.die()` function?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? The answers you got so far actually answer 3 different questions.

Comment: I am pretty sure the behavior of php's [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is what is required. Especially when you look at the code comment: "it worked". You can see that the JS interpreter *died* because there was a script error.

Comment: @bfavaretto I want to stop the .foo click event happening if the doSomething fun 1 == 2 without any errors in the console like using die() or throw 'somthin', is it possible?

Comment: Don't throw. Are you trying to prevent a link (`<a href...>`) from being followed when clicked, or removing the click event from the element so that further clicks do nothing?

Comment: Actually, I believe it's neither now... Upvoted the two answers that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @bfavaretto I making animation youtube player, just i need to make sure first the url of the video is correct, the youtube id fun got it from here http://goo.gl/1BPzB (check the answer with 52 up vote) and after cheking the id i want to do the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the code, you probably want to just throw an exception ;-)

```
function doSomething
{
    if(1==2){
        alert("Can I access to your event?");
    }else{
        throw 'blah';
    }
}
```

This will unwind the stack immediately until the exception is caught or it reaches the global level.

Answer (score 2):

You could just return false within the click handler, I suppose. For example:

```
function doSomething () {
    if(1==2){
      alert("Can I access to your event?");
    }else{
      return false; // tell the click handler that this function barfed
    }
}

$(".foo").click(function(){
    if(doSomething() === false){ //check to see if this function had an error
      return false; //prevent execution of code below this conditional
    }
    alert("welcome, 1 == 1 is true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this traditional way

```
function doSomething () {
    if(1==2){
      alert("Can I access to your event?");
      return true;
    }else{
      return false
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
    if(doSomething()){
      alert("welcome, 1 == 1 is true");
    }else{
     alert("Sorry, 1 == 1 is false");
    }
```

}

Comment: @sksallaj sorry did'nt get it ^_^

Comment: lol, noo, i mean I used your solution and implemented it as a working example.. that's all :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could throw [an exception](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp):

```
function doSomething (){
    if (1 == 2) {
        alert("Can I access to your event?");
    } else {
        throw "this is a fatal error";
    }
}

$(".foo").click(function () {
    doSomething();
    alert("welcome, 1 == 1 is true");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v3vy7/)

Of course you should handle that exception to not get errors in your log, maybe like so:

```
$(".foo").click(function () {
    try {
        doSomething();
        alert("welcome, 1 == 1 is true");
    } catch (err) { 
        // do nothing but allow to gracefully continue 
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v3vy7/1/)